# how can I call javascript function when move the focus from one column to another column of the table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have the following column  in table . I want to call the javascript function changecolumn() when I move to another column , here is the code

```js
<script>
 changecolum()
 {
 }
</script>
```

```html
<table id="attendance">
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsSickMarked" data-tag="SickHrs" /> <input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsSickMarked" /></td>
 <td><a href="#" data-pk="SickHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].SickHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].SickHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" data-tag="HolidayHrs" /><input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" /> </td>
 <td class="htInvalid"><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs</a><input  asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs" type="hidden" class="bros"/></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by move to another column? Focus is usually on inputs, not table columns.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to call the javascript function changecolumn() when I move to another column

As @Barmar mentioned, please note that focus usually affect on inputs or editable content etc, not all html elements can be focused.

If you'd like to call js function `changecolumn()` when user click on another column, you can try following workaround.

*Set a flag `data-cindex` indicates the current column index for `td`*

```
<table id="attendance">
    <tr>
        <td data-cindex="0"><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsSickMarked" data-tag="SickHrs" /> <input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsSickMarked" /></td>
        <td data-cindex="1"><a href="#" data-pk="SickHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].SickHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].SickHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>
        <td data-cindex="2"><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" data-tag="HolidayHrs" /><input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" /> </td>
        <td data-cindex="3" class="htInvalid"><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Trace previous selected column index and compare it with current column index on td click event*

```
$(function () {

    //set default value based on your actual requirement
    var selected_c_index = 0;

    $("table#attendance tr td").click(function () {
        var cindex = $(this).data("cindex");
        if (selected_c_index!=cindex) {
            selected_c_index = cindex;
            
            changecolum();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: I posted wrong meaning this question . Sorry for that. Actually I want to trigger changecolumn() when we click any other column or move out  the focus from table, Not sure after the click in  Holiday column, the  the user will click to another column in the same row or in another row. There is chance for moving out the focus from  the table  to another object other than the table. For example after typing holiday Hrs ,  user will move the pointer to the save btn. That cases , the code will  not work.

Answer (score 0):

like @Fei_Han and @Barmer said:

> not all html elements can be focused.

just to complete @Fei_Han answer, in focusable element there is **Focusout** event listener. I've made you a snippet.

If you click on an input and then click away. it will run consoleThis function.

```js
function consoleThis() {
        console.log("Lost Focus")
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onfocusout="consoleThis()"><input type="text" name="" placeholder="something"></td>
            <td onfocusout="consoleThis()"><input type="email" name="" placeholder="email" id=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td onfocusout="consoleThis()"><input type="text" name="" placeholder="anything" id=""></td>
            <td onfocusout="consoleThis()"><input type="email" name="" placeholder="email" id=""></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```